# Removing lines matching a pattern

Tags: linux, shell, loops, grep

I want to search for patterns in a file and remove the lines containing the pattern. To do this, am using:

```
originalLogFile='sample.log'
outputFile='3.txt'
temp=$originalLogFile 

 while read line
 do
    echo "Removing" 
    echo $line
    grep -v "$line" $temp > $outputFile
    temp=$outputFile
done <$whiteListOfErrors
```

This works fine for the first iteration. For the second run, it throws :

```
grep: input file ‘3.txt’ is also the output
```

Any solutions or alternate methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should be equivalent

```
grep -v -f  "$whiteListOfErrors" "$originalLogFile" > "$outputFile"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
originalLogFile='sample.log'
outputFile='3.txt'
tmpfile='tmp.txt'
temp=$originalLogFile 
while read line
do
   echo "Removing" 
   echo $line
   grep -v "$line" $temp > $outputFile
   cp $outputfile $tmpfile
   temp=$tmpfile
done <$whiteListOfErrors
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `sed` for this:

```
sed '/.*pattern.*/d' file
```

If you have multiple patterns you may use the `-e` option

```
sed -e '/.*pattern1.*/d' -e '/.*pattern2.*/d' file
```

If you have `GNU sed` (typical on Linux) the `-i` option is comfortable as it can modify the original file instead of writing to a new file. (But handle with care, in order to not overwrite your original)

Comment: The leading and trailing `.*` are superfluous. Anyway, go with @1_CR's answer.

Comment: yeah `grep` is better here

Comment: And, using `sed` like this doesn't handle multiple patterns well.

Answer (score 0):

Used this to fix the problem:

```
while read line
do
    echo "Removing" 
    echo $line
    grep -v "$line" $temp | tee $outputFile 
    temp=$outputFile
done <$falseFailures
```

Answer (score -1):

Trivial solution might be to work with alternating files; e.g.

```
idx=0
while ...
    let next='(idx+1) % 2'
    grep ... $file.$idx > $file.$next
    idx=$next
```

A more elegant might be the creation of one large `grep` command

```
args=( )
while read line; do args=( "${args[@]}" -v "$line" ); done < $whiteList
grep "${args[@]}" $origFile
```